# normalising vertex and normal coordinates Open GL ES 2.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I have a model created in blender and exported to an .obj file. I have written a parser that reads in the co ordinates for of the vertices textures and normals. I have been dividing all the co-ordinats by a constant applicable to the program to reduce the size of the mode so that it fits the screen(this is a temporary measure). This works fine except for the lighting which doesn't work, Im left with a black 3D object when it should be coloured. After researching it on the web, I think this could be because the normals aren't of length one? If this is true how can I scale my co-ordinates so that they fit the screen and get the lighting to work?

Vertex Shader

```
//
//  Created by Jake Cunningham on 13/10/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Jake Cunningham. All rights reserved.
//

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

attribute vec2 TextCo;
varying vec2 textCoOut;

void main()
{
vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

colorVarying = diffuseColor * nDotVP;

gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
textCoOut = TextCo;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
//  Created by Jake Cunningham on 13/10/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Jake Cunningham. All rights reserved.
//

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

varying lowp vec2 textCoOut;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
gl_FragColor = colorVarying * texture2D(texture, textCoOut);

}
```

code from view controller.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfVerticies * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, arrayOfVerticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_normalArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_normalArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GLKVertexAttribNormal, loader.currentCountOfNormals  * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3,loader.arrayOfNormals , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_textureArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_textureArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_textureBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfTextureCoordinates * sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, loader.arrayOftextureCoOrdinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));


glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Comment: Can you share your shader code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using shaders, you can use the `normalize()` operation on your vertices and normals within your GLSL code.

You could also have a look at the [obj2opengl script](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/) which scales, centers, and normalizes your model, converting OBJ files into header files ready for iOS implementation. I've also extended that script into [mtl2opengl](http://www.rendoncepeda.com/home/projects/mtl2opengl/) to include support for MTL files and make it a bit more light-weight (with an Xcode example too).

Comment: cheers. Ive implemented that but still getting a black cube. Might have an additional error.